# In extjs how to get uploaded file's contents

Tags: php, file-upload, extjs4

I am working on file upload functionality in extjs+php. I want to upload file or image from extjs and need to send it to server side which i am designing in PHP. In extjs i have view file's code as-

```
Ext.define('Balaee.view.kp.dnycontent.Content', 
{
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
    requires:[
              'Balaee.view.kp.dnycontent.ContentView'
              ],
    id:'ContentId',
    alias:'widget.Content',
    title:'This day in a history',
    items:[
     {
        xtype: 'fileuploadfield',
        hideLabel: true,
        emptyText: 'Select a file to upload...',
        id: 'upfile',
        //name:'file',
         width: 220
}],
    buttons:[
    {
        text: 'Upload',
        handler: function () {
            var file = Ext.getCmp('upfile').getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0];            console.log(file);
             var reader = new FileReader();
             filecontent=reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
             console.log(filecontent);
        }
    }
]
```

});

So when I am trying to upload animage file with the above code.The above line:
`Ext.getCmp('upfile').getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0];` stores information of the file as:

```
File {
    webkitRelativePath: "", 
    lastModifiedDate: Tue Jul 14 2009 11:02:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), 
    name: "Koala.jpg", 
    type: "image/jpeg", 
    size: 780831…
 }
```

i.e. Information related to file is retrieved. But the actual file contents are not getting retrieved. So what do I need to modify to get actual uploaded file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of the file is not returned from `readAsBinaryString`, you have to set the onload callback that will be triggered when the file contents are read.

```
reader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
    console.log(oFREvent.target.result);
};
```

Comment: @user1722857 do you intend to upload the string to a server in an attempt to upload a file via ajax? If so you should use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData) instead.

Comment: Actually sir now i got stucked at what to send to server side. Whether i should send only file and its related information to server which i got retrived by "Ext.getCmp('upfile').getEl().down('input[type=file]').dom.files[0];" But how file's contents will get transfer to server side? What modifications i will need to do ,to transfer uploaded file with its contents to server side? Please sir can you guide me